# Properly installing Android SDK for cordova on Fedora23

Tags: android, cordova, fedora-23

Hi Guys I have been having trouble on setting up my android sdk on my Fedora23 OS this is for a Cordova development. I have checked my Environment Variables  on my terminal using `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and verifying whats installed correctly using `cordova requirements` command and this is the result it gave me

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed 
Android target: not installed 
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: installed 

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: not installed 
Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple OS X
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

How come that the **Android Target** was not installed while **Gradle** was installed?
and also how come whenever I tried to use `android` commands its not working

have I did something incorrect? this is how I setup my android sdk

- I downloaded the android-sdk from [Android Studio's site](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)
- I extracted it using `tar` command
- Moved it to /opt/
- Added the android sdk home to my environment at `/etc/bashrc`

its been two days now and I still dont have it running someone help please

**UPDATE**
inside my bashrc are the ff:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH="$HOME/opt/android-sdk-linux/android-sdk/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME
```

Comment: You should use ~/.bashrc to add the path. Can you paste your bashrc?

Comment: @Breixo hi I have added it now on my post

Comment: sorry for downvote, misclick :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your bashrc should be

```
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH="/opt/android-sdk-linux/android-sdk/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME
```

Comment: what made you decide to remove `$HOME`..what does `$HOME` actually do ?? I'm kinda new on Linux OS sorry

Comment: $HOME contains your user directory, and i guess you have the sdk in /opt/android-sdk-linux

Comment: Oh I see ok I'll give this a try